# ejabberd getting 404 Not Found at /http-bind

Tags: ejabberd

i'm having trouble setting up external xmpp server for nextcloud with my ejabberd server in combination with jsxc / xmpp-cloud-auth.

In nextcloud external server config it shown the error:
XMPP domain: https://cloud.XXX.com:5280
BOSH url: /http-bind/
Invalid XML received. Maybe https://cloud.XXX.com/http-bind/ was redirected. You should use an absolute url.

If i navigate with the broswser i'm getting an 404 Not Found at /http-bind, also my admin panel gets shown a bit weird and shows not everything (as you can see in the photo).

I'm using:
ubuntu 20.04.1
Apache2 2.4.41
ejabberd 20.12
Nextcloud
JavaScript XMPP Chat 4.2.0
xmpp-cloud-auth v2.0.4

I used this article to set up the system: https://github.com/jsxc/xmpp-cloud-auth/wiki/raspberry-pi-en

Does anyone having an idea why this happens? What could be the reason for a 404 error?
Whom asks http-bind to get an answer? And what should be the desired output?

firewall settings seems to be ok. No DNS settings are set at the moment because its only running local. The there is an Windows DNS server running in the network which give the server the hostname cloud.XXX.com

#### Steps to reproduce the behavior

1. typing https://cloud.XXX.com:5280/http-bind in the browser
2. getting 404 error

#### Environment

- **JSXC version:**
  JavaScript XMPP Chat 4.2.0
  xmpp-cloud-auth v2.0.4
- **Host system and version:**
  Nextcloud 20.0.4
  ubuntu 20.04.1
  Apache2 2.4.41
- **Browser vendor and version:**
  firefox 84.0.1
- **Any browser plugins enabled?**
  no
- **XMPP server vendor and version:**
  ejabberd 20.12
- **Is your XMPP server working with other clients as expected?**
  no...

apache2 vhost is customized to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www

    <FilesMatch ".php$">
        <If "-f %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.nextcloud.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </If>
    </FilesMatch>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ProxyPass /http-bind/ http://localhost:5280/http-bind/
    ProxyPassReverse /http-bind/ http://localhost:5280/http-bind/
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =cloud.XXX.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

my ejabberd.yml:

```
---
loglevel: 4
log_rotate_count: 0
log_rotate_date: ""

hosts:
  - "cloud.spacyal.com"

certfiles:
  - "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"

## TLS configuration
define_macro:
  'TLS_CIPHERS': "HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!3DES:@STRENGTH"
  'TLS_OPTIONS':
    - "no_sslv3"
    - "no_tlsv1"
    - "no_tlsv1_1"
    - "cipher_server_preference"
    - "no_compression"
    ## 'DH_FILE': "/path/to/dhparams.pem"
    ## generated with: openssl dhparam -out dhparams.pem 2048

c2s_ciphers: 'TLS_CIPHERS'
s2s_ciphers: 'TLS_CIPHERS'
c2s_protocol_options: 'TLS_OPTIONS'
s2s_protocol_options: 'TLS_OPTIONS'
## c2s_dhfile: 'DH_FILE'
## s2s_dhfile: 'DH_FILE'

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
    protocol_options: 'TLS_OPTIONS'
  -
    port: 5223
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    tls: true
    protocol_options: 'TLS_OPTIONS'
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    protocol_options: 'TLS_OPTIONS'
    request_handlers:
      /api: mod_http_api
      /bosh: mod_bosh
      ## /captcha: ejabberd_captcha
      ## /upload: mod_http_upload
      /ws: ejabberd_http_ws
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    protocol_options: 'TLS_OPTIONS'
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /.well-known/acme-challenge: ejabberd_acme
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000


## Disabling digest-md5 SASL authentication. digest-md5 requires plain-text
## password storage (see auth_password_format option).
disable_sasl_mechanisms:
  - "digest-md5"
  - "X-OAUTH2"

s2s_use_starttls: required

## Store the plain passwords or hashed for SCRAM:
auth_password_format: scram
auth_method: external
extauth_program: "/usr/bin/socket localhost 23662"
auth_use_cache: false
## Full path to a script that generates the image.
## captcha_cmd: "/usr/share/ejabberd/captcha.sh"

acl:
  admin:
     user:
       - "admin"

  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128

access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          acl: loopback
          acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            acl: loopback
            acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  ## mod_delegation: {}   # for xep0356
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_echo: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  ## mod_http_upload:
  ##   put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
  mod_last: {}
  ## mod_mam:
  ##   ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
  ##   ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
  ##   ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
  ##   ## db_type: sql
  ##   assume_mam_usage: true
  ##   default: always
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      mam: true
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_pres_counter:
    count: 5
    interval: 60
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      "eu.siacs.conversations.axolotl.*":
        access_model: open
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  ## mod_register:
  ##   ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
  ##   ## network (see access_rules section above).
  ##   ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
  ##   ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
  ##   ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
  ##   ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_sic: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard:
    search: false
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version: {}
```

ejabberd.log says:

```
2020-12-25 22:03:38.847 [notice] <0.128.0>@lager_file_backend:154 Changed loghwm of /var/log/ejabberd/error.log to 100
2020-12-25 22:03:38.847 [notice] <0.128.0>@lager_file_backend:154 Changed loghwm of /var/log/ejabberd/ejabberd.log to 100
2020-12-25 22:03:38.908 [info] <0.114.0>@ejabberd_config:load:80 Loading configuration from /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml
2020-12-25 22:03:38.919 [warning] <0.114.0>@ejabberd_config_transformer:warn_removed_module:514 Module mod_echo is deprecated and was automatically removed from the configuration. Please adjust your configuration file accordingly. Hint: run `ejabberdctl dump-config` command to view current configuration as it is seen by ejabberd.
2020-12-25 22:03:39.010 [warning] <0.114.0>@gen_mod:warn_soft_dep_fail:576 Module mod_mam is recommended for module mod_muc but is not found in the config
2020-12-25 22:03:39.023 [info] <0.114.0>@ejabberd_config:load:87 Configuration loaded successfully
2020-12-25 22:03:39.262 [info] <0.359.0>@gen_mod:start_modules:124 Loading modules for cloud.spacyal.com
2020-12-25 22:03:39.431 [info] <0.473.0>@mod_mqtt:init_topic_cache:523 Building MQTT cache for cloud.spacyal.com, this may take a while
2020-12-25 22:03:39.490 [info] <0.114.0>@ejabberd_cluster_mnesia:wait_for_sync:123 Waiting for Mnesia synchronization to complete
2020-12-25 22:03:39.629 [info] <0.114.0>@ejabberd_app:start:62 ejabberd 20.01-1 is started in the node ejabberd@localhost in 0.91s
2020-12-25 22:03:39.629 [info] <0.380.0>@ejabberd_listener:init:151 Start accepting TCP connections at [::]:5222 for ejabberd_c2s
2020-12-25 22:03:39.629 [info] <0.381.0>@ejabberd_listener:init:151 Start accepting TLS connections at [::]:5223 for ejabberd_c2s
2020-12-25 22:03:39.629 [info] <0.382.0>@ejabberd_listener:init:151 Start accepting TCP connections at [::]:5269 for ejabberd_s2s_in
2020-12-25 22:03:39.631 [info] <0.383.0>@ejabberd_listener:init:151 Start accepting TLS connections at [::]:5443 for ejabberd_http
2020-12-25 22:03:39.631 [info] <0.384.0>@ejabberd_listener:init:151 Start accepting TLS connections at [::]:5280 for ejabberd_http
2020-12-25 22:03:39.632 [info] <0.385.0>@ejabberd_listener:init:151 Start accepting TCP connections at [::]:1883 for mod_mqtt
2020-12-25 22:03:39.632 [info] <0.477.0>@ejabberd_listener:init:151 Start accepting TCP connections at 10.0.0.4:7777 for mod_proxy65_stream
2020-12-25 22:03:59.226 [info] <0.384.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:256 (<0.531.0>) Accepted connection [::ffff:10.0.0.3]:60338 -> [::ffff:10.0.0.4]:5280
```

any ideas?? I would be very grateful! I've been trying for 2 days and can't solve it

THANKS SO MUCH !!

and merry christmas :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check how you configure. If you tell ejabberd to listen in path `/bosh`, then that's the URL you must use. For example:

```
listen:
  ...
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: false
    request_handlers:
      /bosh: mod_bosh
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      /bosh: mod_bosh
```

This works:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5280/bosh/
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><title>ejabberd mod_bosh</title><style>body {
...

$ curl -k https://localhost:5443/bosh/
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><title>ejabberd mod_bosh</title><style>body {
...
```